# Python: alternative to the selenium Webdriver that google can not recognize as Automatic test software

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, webdriver, bots

I am trying to build a python bot that logs into my Google account automatically with python.
I tried with selenium but as soon as the bot had opened the page the login wouldn't work. Google said you can't log in to your account with Automatic test software. Is there an alternative to selenium Google does not recognize as Automatic Test software? Maybe automatic software which is not for testing?

Comment: I'm guessing that simply changing the Selenium browser's default user-agent would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can already do this (by exploiting a bypass).

The following link comes from the Google OAuth Playground, ensuring the practicality of the link. It most likely won't expire any time soon.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

You can use that link (ie. `driver.get()`) to log into your Google account.

This bypasses the automation checks allows you to log into Google using Selenium. At least for now.

You don't need a Selenium alternative to do this :)

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.